# Google maps v3 zoom end

Tags: google-maps

I have a problem with google maps v3 zoom_change, as it doesn't solve my need perfectly.

I have 2 unmet requirements:

- I need to get the bounds and show points that are inside the bounds **after** the user clicked in zoom control and zoom has been reajusted in the map. The method zoom_change do it **before** reajusting zoom, and the bounds aren't the ones I need.
- The method zoom_change is called every time, for example,  whenever I execute *fitBounds* or *setZoom*. I only need it when when zoomcontrol is clicked or when mousewheel is moved.

Is there a solution available in the v3 API for those issues?

Answer (score 11):

Listen for the idle event.

From [Google Maps Javascript API V3 Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.idle):

> idle: This event is fired when the map becomes idle after panning or
>   zooming.

Comment: This - thank you. I was handling dragging and zooming individually. This is much more elegant.

Comment: Helpful, but link should point to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.idle

Answer (score 7):

The event is called `zoom_changed` (NOT`zoom_change`). The event handler of this event is called AFTER the zoom has changed. It is indeed not straightforward to distnguish the zoom change caused by the user from that one caused by the program. A possible solution is to maintain a "global" variable say `userZoom` which denotes whether the user triggered the zoom.

```
var userZoom = true; // initial value: be prepared for user action
// Install listener
google.maps.event.addListener(Map.self, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    if (userZoom) {      
        // the user changed zoom: do what should be done
    }
    else {
        // zoom change caused by a program action: ignore
    }
    userZoom = true;  // be prepared for the user zoom action    
});
```

Before you call any of the program actions that change the zoom, set `userZoom = false`, e.g.

```
userZoom = false;
map.setZoom(9);
```

Comment: this is an excellent, transparent solution. Thanks for sharing

Comment: This answer is potentially useful but does not address the issue of detecting `zoom_end`. `zoom-changed` fires when the new zoom level is demanded - not when the zoom animation has completed, which is what the OP wants (and so do I).

Answer (score 0):

The only real way I have found is to create a custom zoom control on the map,

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls?utm_source=welovemaspdevelopers&utm_campaign=stackoverflow#CustomEvents

and then set an event listener on the control,

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls?utm_source=welovemaspdevelopers&utm_campaign=stackoverflow#ControlModification.

Clearly not elegant, but an option.